# Why is JFrame not adding a component properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I'm having an error when trying to add a component to a JFrame.

This is the first class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
public class FrameG extends JFrame
{

private static final String MOVE_UP = "move up";
public static int frameID = 1;
private static JFrame window = new JFrame();
private static openWin frame = new frame01();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    window.setSize(1500,900);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(true);
    frame.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), MOVE_UP);
    frame.getActionMap().put(MOVE_UP, new movement());
    mainloop();
}
private static void mainloop()
{
    window.removeAll();
    switch(frameID)
    {
        case 1:
            frame = new frame01();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            System.out.println(frame);
            window.add(frame);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrameG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    mainloop();
}
}
class movement extends AbstractAction
{
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
}
```

and the second class (it extends a class with an abstract paint method that extends JComponent):

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class frame01 extends openWin{
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D pic = (Graphics2D) g;
    pic.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

The error may be the invalid part, but i'm not sure what it is:

`frameg.frame01[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]`

Comment: `private static openWin frame = new frame01();` seems fishy. Please expand on that line.

Comment: You're mainLoop method will cause a StackOverflowException; you shouldn't be updating the ui from outside of the EDT; you should be overriding paintComponent and not paint and calling super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting; based on your code, I'm not sure how you would know any difference between one cycle of the mainLoop and the other; also you're frame01 isn't actually painting anything, so it'll probably look the same as the default content of the frame anyway

Answer (score 3):

You code shows a distinct lack of understanding into how Swing works

This...

```
private static void mainloop()
{
    window.removeAll();
    switch(frameID)
    {
        case 1:
            frame = new frame01();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            System.out.println(frame);
            window.add(frame);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrameG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    mainloop();
}
```

Is a bad idea of two reasons, the first been that it will eventually generate a `StackOverflowException`, the second been that it violates the single thread rules of Swing.

Normally, a `while-loop` would generally be better, but as you're dealing with Swing based components you should consider using either a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker`, depending on what you are hoping to achieve.

Constantly adding and remove components also seems like a weird idea, but there's no context to the question to know what it is you're hoping to achieve.  Having said that, as a general rule, if you want to switch between views a `CardLayout` is generally considered the preferred solution

This...

```
public class frame01 extends openWin{
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D pic = (Graphics2D) g;
        pic.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

is simply doing nothing, other then breaking the paint chain, which could cause no end of weird paint artefacts to be generated.  All you code does if temporarily changes the background color of the `Graphics` context, but since you don't paint anything with it, it's effectively meaningless

As a general rule, it's recommended to override the `paintComponent` method of Swing components (and call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting).

I would highly recommend that you take a look at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has lots of problems. The line `private static openWin frame = new frame01();` seems fishy as I said in my comment. But its not the worst part:

**THIS:**

```
private static void mainloop()
{
    window.removeAll();
    switch(frameID)
    {
        case 1:
            frame = new frame01();
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            System.out.println(frame);
            window.add(frame);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrameG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    mainloop();
}
```

Is **BAD**! And it probably breaks since you are constantly creating a `new frame01()` and adding it to your `window`.

Also **DO NOT** override `paint` but `paintComponent`. Another thing I dont get is why override it in a separate `class` and not in `openWin` itself.

Another thing, **DO NOT SLEEP THE MAIN THREAD**, if you really must then run your own and put IT to sleep.

What is the purpose of this code? I'm trying to understand it so I can help you redesign it.

**PS:** not really an answer, just a bit longer than a comment.

Comment: as for the     private static openWin frame = new frame01();  this is used since so that frame01 can hold multiple classes but not at the same time.

I tried paintcomponent, but it had the same effect. Also, openWin is abstract.   I'm not worried about that, but when I try to add it it just doesn't do anything and i think the cause is whatever the invalid thing is

Comment: @pi_squared As I said that line is not the worst part. It seems like the whole design of your(presumably) game is weak. Why are you looping the `mainLoop()` recursively?

Comment: i'm going to add a way to interact with the component later. it's just the issue that I can't get the window.add(frame); working

Comment: @pi_squared I assure you the `window.add(frame);` executes correctly. Your problem is not how you do it but how many times you do it. You have to redesign the loop(even better the whole program). First get rid of that nasty recursive call, second don't create new frame every time but only once and don't add it every loop but once. On a side note the `paint` method you overridden does nothing.

Comment: @pi_squared Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438715/flickering-java-gui-in-ubuntu-14-04) will help you redesign the loop. That is a question I asked some time ago and it has a similar loop, mind that it uses a `Canvas` and the `run()` method runs on a separate `Thread`.

Comment: I've identified the problem. it's the removeAll method. I'm trying to animate it by placing a component and then removing it to replace it with an updated component. is this wrong?

Comment: @pi_squared yes it is wrong! as I said before you need only one frame! instead of creating a new one update the one you got. And again CHANGE YOUR DESIGN even if you think you solved a problem I can guarantee that with this design you will encounter a new one.

Comment: how do you update a component? all i know is how to make a component,  paint it, and add it to the JFrame.

Comment: @pi_squared `JFrame.repaint()` is there to aid you with that! I recommend reading about `Swing` & `awt` to understand it better. There is nothing wrong with learning how to do things before you do them.

Answer (score 1):

**Never use a Thread and it's start and stops as a timer**. Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead. Also you've created a recursive function to implement an infinite loop which is very wired and prone to fail. Swing has it's own thread and when you mix it up with another threads unconsciously it transform your code to a monster we are all afraid of.